# Check if the code-base is compatible with a specific version of python3

Tags: python, python-3.x

Given a reasonably sized codebase with few hundreds of python files, what is the best way to tell if the code is compatible with a specific version of python (e.g 3.4.4 / 3.5.2)

One way of course is to run the code against the specific python version - but getting the coverage on all files is the question.

Comment: If you want to check syntax, you can try `python -m compileall` from the command line in the root folder of your project. Whether the code actually functions as expected (and whether for example all attributes and methods of used objects exist, etc.) can't be checked without testing.

Comment: fabulous, this is what I wanted.. thanks @Grismar

Answer (score 0):

So far I know there is no way to check if a python file is compatible without try to execute it. However you can get the version of a module by doing `module.__version__` (doesn't work for all modules), and you can get the python version with the `sys` module:

```
import sys
print(sys.version)
```